# Opening Xamarin Application Crash Report in an XCode Project

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

We've developed a Xamarin mobile application in VS for Mac. Recently, the application began hard crashing on the iPad. I've downloaded a TestFlight crash report from Apple Store connect and opened it in XCode. Apple details the steps to symbolicate the file [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report#Symbolicate-the-crash-report-in-Xcode). After locating the dSYM file, I was able to symbolicate the crash file; however, it's still unclear what is causing the issue. XCode has the option to open the crash report in a project.

[image]

So far, I've not be able to find a way to open the relevant files in the VS directory or import the relvant files into an XCode project. Is the even possible. How else can I go about determining the lines of code causing the error?

Comment: have you tried using a crash reporting tool like AppCenter.ms or raygun.io?  If the crash is happening in managed code they produce much more meaningful error reports

Comment: Did you look at the device log under Devices and Simulators?
Xcode->Window->Devices and Simulators->View Devices Logs

Answer (score 0):

You try to open XCode choose Window > Organizer and click Crash. For details, you can refer to the XCode help document ([About Crashes organizer](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev861f46ea8)). Another way that you can do is to try to log into [itunesconnect.apple.com](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/login) and select "My Apps" to find your app to see the crash.